# Xcode Build Error - CocoaPods - ld: warning: directory not found

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

I have an old iOS app I'm trying to rebuild for newer hardware. It was originally developed for iOS 6. It uses CocoaPods for a few dependencies. I've run pod install etc.

When I try to build I get the following linker errors:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InventoryScanner-hantgwmqafypwugwnyerkcfurgwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ASIHTTPRequest'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InventoryScanner-hantgwmqafypwugwnyerkcfurgwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Reachability'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InventoryScanner-hantgwmqafypwugwnyerkcfurgwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SBJson'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InventoryScanner-hantgwmqafypwugwnyerkcfurgwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SVProgressHUD'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/InventoryScanner-hantgwmqafypwugwnyerkcfurgwn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ZXingObjC'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/xxx/Projects/xxx/inventory-scanner/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lASIHTTPRequest
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And here is my Podfile:

```
target "xxx" do
        platform :ios, '8.0'

        pod 'SVProgressHUD'
        pod 'SBJson', '~> 3.2.0'
        pod 'ASIHTTPRequest'
        pod 'ZXingObjC'

        generate_bridge_support!
end
```

What I might be missing?